# Drupal 7 print l() query string showing in special characters

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

In D7, I want to pass the query string as like www.sitename/page-name?query_string[]=8, in hyperlink.

For this I written the below code:

```
<?php print l('Hello','page-name', array('html' => TRUE,'attributes' => array('class' => 'example-class',), 'query' => array('query_string[]=8' => ''))); ?>
```

But it shows like : /page-name?query_string%5B%5D%3D8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to change your syntaxe according documentation page but always same result  :

```
l('Hello','page-name', 
  array('html' => TRUE,
        'attributes' => array('class' => 'example-class',), 
        'query' => array('query_string' => array('8', '9'))
  )
);
```

display :

```
<a href="/page-name?query_string%5B0%5D=8&amp;query_string%5B1%5D=9" class="example-class">Hello</a>
```

So when you try to get values , it's works or not ?